# Is Google Cloud Storage PCI compliant?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pci-compliance, pci-dss

Here is the [Google Cloud Platform: Customer Responsibility Matrix](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCP_Client_Facing_Responsibility_Matrix_PCI_2018.pdf). This document basically goes through all of the PCI DSS requirements and explains what is done by GCP and what is supposed to be done by the customers.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/pci-dss/) document states that Google Cloud Storage is in scope for PCI DSS.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/pci-dss-compliance-in-gcp#cloud_storage) GCP link states that "***Requirement 3.4 stipulates that a PAN must be unreadable anywhere it is stored. While Google automatically offers encryption at rest, it doesn't automatically perform the one-way hashes, truncation, or tokenization that the rules also require.***”

However, I am not able to find proof that explicitly says that Google Cloud storage is PCI compliant as it is a service from a cloud provider.

Is there an official document which claims Google Cloud Storage to be PCI compliant as a service?

A document that talks about how GCP achieved PCI DSS compliance for google cloud storage rather than how to fulfill the requirements for the customer's set-up?

Comment: 1) Samuel's answer is good. 2) Your question does not fit StackOverflow. Move your question to StackExchange's Security site: https://security.stackexchange.com 3) PCI Compliance requires a lot of work on your side as well as Google providing secure infrastructure. 4) Read the Google PCI documents for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are asking two questions here:

(1) **Is Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) Certified?**

(2) **Is Google Cloud Storage (GCS) PCI DSS Compliant?**

Here are the answers available in our public documentation:

1) **GCP is PCI DSS Certified** as this [announcement](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/12/google-cloud-platform-now-pci-data-security-standard-certified.html) and our [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/pci-dss/) clearly state:

> "**Google Cloud undergoes an annual third-party audit to certify
>   individual products against the PCI DSS. This means that these
>   services provide an infrastructure that customers may build their own
>   services or applications** which store, process, or transmit cardholder
>   data."

As you know, PCI DSS is a standard written by credit card companies for handling the security of credit card information from consumers. As our documentation reveals, it is a shared responsibility between the Cloud Provider (GCP), who needs to be certified as a platform, and the consumer/customer (you), whose responsibility it is to implement/build compliant services on GCP.

2) **Cloud Storage is PCI DSS Compliant** as you can see in this [official statement](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/pci-dss/#protecting-customers-card-information)

> "**The following Google Cloud services have been reviewed by an
>   independent Qualified Security Assessor and determined to be PCI DSS
>   3.2 compliant**. This means that these services provide an infrastructure upon which customers may build their own service or
>   application which stores, processes, or transmits cardholder data. We
>   have created this matrix to help explain the shared responsibility
>   between Google and its customers."

Per "Is there an official document which claims Google Cloud Storage to be PCI compliant as a service?" refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/pci-dss/) and [this reference](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/services-in-scope/) that reveals GCS is a service that meets PCI DSS compliance. But of course when you architect a solution that uses GCS you need to do so in a PCI DSS compliant way.

Note that the same statement of shared responsibility is also echoed in the [Google Cloud Platform: Customer Responsibility Matrix](https://cloud.google.com/files/PCI_DSS_Shared_Responsibility_GCP_v32.pdf) that you referenced. **We recommend that Customers reference the responsibility matrix as they pursue PCI compliance and find it a useful tool when conducting their own PCI audits.**

Per "A document that talks about how GCP achieved PCI DSS compliance for google cloud storage rather than how to fulfill the requirements for the customer's set-up?" refer again to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/pci-dss/) that states, "Google Cloud undergoes an annual third-party audit to certify individual products against the PCI DSS."

We also published an [advice on building PCI compliant services on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/pci-dss-compliance-in-gcp) which you referenced. Here is an [example](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/oro-how-gcp-smoothed-our-path-to-pci-dss-compliance) of how to go about building PCI DSS compliant services on GCP. And here's an [example of how a customer's GCS based service meets PCI DSS compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682538/9738014) using our tools.

Hope this helps to clarify what is stated about PCI DSS compliance in our public docs.